# Javascript date object without time zone

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, date, datetime

I've recently implemented a webview based mobile app for a cloudbased system, and I've come across a frustrating problem.

We store the dates in the database in the following format:

```
2016-10-11T11:09:00
```

In the desktop applications it comes up correctly as **2016/10/11 11:09:00**.

However, in the mobile app (we use phonegap, so it's HTML + JS based), when I get this date string from the database via a PHP call, and I convert it, using 'new Date("2016-10-11T11:09:00")', it shows up with a timezone conversion, so for instance if I'm in GMT + 2, it will be **2016/10/11 13:09:00**.

How can I prevent this?

Whenever I show the dates on the views, I use a date.toString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") formatting.

Also, I'm open to any suggestions, in terms of storing and showing datetime across multiple platforms. I found this **yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss** formatting to be quite good and videly used, until I bumped into this javascript problem.

(I'm not a javascript or HTML expert, as far as you can tell)

LE: I don't want to convert the date to UTC string, I want the actual Date object, to be consistent with the database value, cause i'm hooking it up to an HTML datetime picker via AngularJS.

Comment: should that be `new Date("2016-10-11T11:09:00Z")` ... note the Z ... in browsers (firefox, edge) this can make a difference (no difference in Chrum)

Comment: I just tried new Date("2016-10-11T11:09:00Z") and new Date("2016-10-11T11:09:00") in chromes developer tools, and they give the same thing.

Comment: which is exactly what I said ... no difference in Chrum, but Firefox and Edge do have differences - unless your localtime is UTC

Comment: oh right, i started replying before you edited the comment.
the "Z" won't help in the mobile apps webview, either

Comment: If your app is used worldwide, you probably want to store UTC in your database, and have the time rendered in whatever the local time zone is of the user, no?

Comment: `the "Z" won't help in the mobile apps webview` - you're saying the Z makes no difference?

Comment: Adding "Z" in v8 based environments (at least Chrome and node.js) makes no difference, because v8 defaults to UTC when timezone is not defined. Also Safari has the same behavior. Firefox treats them as local time timestamps as recommended by RFC 2822.

Comment: Not storing time zones is a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

What is it that you actually want to achieve? If you want to show the timestamps always as they are ignoring timezone information, you might make things quite confusing to the user when those timestamps might show future time to some of the users. For example: someone modifies data and another user in US west coast views the data and sees the timestamp pointing to the future.

Maybe something you wan to use is Data.toUTCString(), that shows the timestamp so that you will have GMT as a timezone. Then it will be clear that to the users that this timestamp is not in their timezone. Also you might want to have timezone information appended to the timestamp string so that the conversions happen correctly. If you your timestamps are in UTC (or Zulu time) you can add "Z" to the end of the string. RFC 2822 Section 3.3 defines that date and time **should** express local time, but at least with node.js if you leave timezone information out, it seems to express UTC time. So adding the timezone information will make your life easier (would be even better if you would add timezone information in the in the string that you store in your database).

As an example:

```
var timestamp = "2016-10-11T11:09:00";
var d = new Date(timestamp);
// or
d = new Date(timestamp + "Z");

// Then showing the date
d.toString();
// or without the converting it to user's local timezone
d.toUTCString();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but what I want to achieve, is that the Date object would be stripped down of the timezone offset. This toUTCString() function only helps, when I want to convert it to a string.
I need the date object to be consistent with the value from the database, because i'm displaying it in an HTML time input.

Comment: Then you need to add the timezone information to the string you get from the the database, expecting you get a string. Date object will always have timezone information and you should not try to get around this.

Comment: I did a quick test so that I ran 'new Date("2016-10-11T13:00:00")' with Firefox and node.js and results were different. Node.js treated the date string as UTC timestamp while Firefox treated it as a local time (as recommended by RFC 2822). Like I said earlier, Date will always have timezone information. If you leave it out from the date string, it's up to the client side implementation what they will return.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and define your own custom date formatter:

```
var formatter= 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss';
var date = new Date('July 17, 2018 03:24:00');
var time = moment(date).format(formatter);
console.log('Time: ',time);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mkotsollaris/3krdttm3/

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue. Storing in `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` format, but needed to convert it to date on client for a countdown timer calculation (needed to create 2nd date -> subtract difference -> create countdown timer). Logic was correct in browser, incorrect and inconsistent in Ionic2/cordova app webviews. Interesting: my wife and I both have the same phone make/model, and the dates would show up different on hers than mine (!).

Haven't extensively tested, but here is a little function that takes the string and returns a date... working consistently on my phones and browser:

```
const someDateStrFromServer: string = "2017-08-26T15:30:25";
const date: Date = DateUtils.overrideTimezone(someDateStringFromServer);

// these methods are in Class DateUtils {}
// input: string, output: Date
public static overrideTimezone(dateStr: string): Date {
    const date: Date = new Date(dateStr);
    const hours: number = date.getHours();
    const tIndex: number = dateStr.indexOf("T");
    const dateStrHours: number = +(dateStr.slice(tIndex + 1, tIndex + 3));
    const tzOffset =  DateUtils.getTimezoneOffset("h");

    // compares hours sliced from string and hours from date. if different,
    // then I know timezone was calculated into the Date

    if (dateStrHours === hours) return date;  // everything's OK

    // webview factored in timezone, so add it back to correct
    else return new Date(date.setHours(date.getHours() + tzOffset));

}

// can scale it to include "ms", "s", "m", etc
public static getTimezoneOffset(unit = "h") {
    switch(unit) {
        case "h": 
            return (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
        default:
            return (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this little function for getting your result

```
function getCorrectString(dateTimeString){
     var a  = new Date(dateTimeString);
     return a.getFullYear()+'/'
     +('00'+(a.getMonth()+1)).substring(('00'+(a.getMonth()+1)).length-2) +'/'
     +('00'+a.getDate()).substring(('00'+a.getDate()).length-2)+' '
     +('00'+a.getHours()).substring(('00'+a.getHours()).length-2)+':'
     +('00'+a.getMinutes()).substring(('00'+a.getMinutes()).length-2)+':'
     +('00'+a.getSeconds()).substring(('00'+a.getSeconds()).length-2);
}

getCorrectString('2016-10-11T11:09:00')

//result :
//"2016/10/11 11:09:00"
```